# Jquery function and use cpu load 100 %

Tags: jquery, animation

I put my code clean for know the problem and why when load the cpu get 100 % , i see in firefox and others navigators as chrome the problem cpu 100% when the website load this animation , i don´t know what´s bad but only happend when load this website and with this animation

```
$.fn.stars=function(settings) {
        var config = {
            'i' : '',    // image URL
            'c' : 50,    // clear: radius around the mouse to not fill with stars
            'd' : .00005,// density: how many stars per pixel to show - KEEP IT LOW!
            'm' : 100,    // maximum size of stars
            's' : 1000,  // speed (in ms) of star appearance
            'l' : 2000,  // length of time star stays on page
            'f' : 2000,  // fading time
            'h' : 2000   // max hide time before a star appears again somewhere else
        };
        if (settings) {
            $.extend(config, settings);
        }
        config.s+=config.h;
        config.l+=config.s;
        config.f+=config.l;
        function getTransformProperty() {
            var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform'];
            var p;
            while (p = properties.shift()) {
                if (typeof document.body.style[p] != 'undefined') {
                    return p;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        this.each(function() {
            var w=this.offsetWidth, h=this.offsetHeight;
            var ol=this.offsetLeft, ot=this.offsetTop;
            var canvas=this;
            var pixels=w*h;
            var num_stars=pixels*config.d;
            function create_star(){
                var t=Math.random()*config.h;
                var $e;
                var s=config.m*Math.random();
                var pl=ol+(w-s)*Math.random();
                var pt=ot+(h-s)*Math.random();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var html=config.i==''?'<div class="star">*</div>':'<img class="star" src="'+config.i+'" />';
                    $e=$(html)
                        .css({
                            "width":0,
                            "height":0,
                            "position":"absolute",
                            "left":pl+s/2,
                            "top":pt+s/2
                        });
                    $e
                        .appendTo(canvas)
                        .animate({
                            "width":s,
                            "height":s,
                            "left":pl,
                            "top":pt
                        },config.s,'linear');
                },t);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $e
                        .animate({
                            "width":0,
                            "height":0,
                            "left":pl+s/2,
                            "top":pt+s/2
                        },config.f-config.l);
                },t+config.l,'linear');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $e.remove();
                    setTimeout(create_star, 1);
                },t+config.f);
            }
            for (var i=0; i<num_stars; ++i) {
                create_star();
            }
        });
        function rotate(){
            $('.star').each(function(){
                if (!this.trProp) {
                    this.trProp=getTransformProperty();
                    this.deg=Math.random()*360;
                    this.speed=Math.random()*5;
                }
                this.deg=(this.deg+this.speed)%360;
                this.style[this.trProp]='rotate('+this.deg+'deg)';
            });
            setTimeout(rotate, 40);
        }
        rotate();
        return this;
    };
```

Please i try know what it´s bad , i pay the people help for know the problem or which the best configuration for fix this problem

YOU CAN SEE THE TEST OF THIS HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/QrnZj/

Thank´s , Regards

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or something so we can see what happens?

Comment: No sorry i haven´t , i try put now

Comment: You can se here http://jsfiddle.net/QrnZj/

Comment: You can verificate this long load cpu into this url http://fiddle.jshell.net/QrnZj/show/

Comment: I get 8% cpu load (ff23/ie10) and 14% chrome27 (coreI7 3770 3.4Ghz)

Comment: I have i5 3210 and all time put my processor in 20% 30 % 60% and dow 18 % , etc , with firefox